# Trouble getting razor and aspx to play nicely

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on converting some of the partial views in my MVC 3 app (which I recently converted from MVC 2, using the MS tool) from ascx to cshtml (Razor).

Simply put: I'm trying to do a Html.RenderPartial of a Razor partial view, directly from an aspx Master Page. The Razor partial view simply has "Hello World" in it -- no @model or @inherits or anything. When I run my app, at this point I get the following error: "The view at .....cshtml must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl."  In other words, it looks like it's looking for a non-razor view.

So.. If I explicitly put "@inherits ViewUserControl" at the top of my razor partial, I get a different error: "...cshtml.Execute(): No suitable method found to override."

I created a new MVC 3 app from scratch and tried the same thing at its simplest. An aspx master page that does a RenderPartial on a razor partial. And it works fine. But this big hairy existing app is too big to do a start from scratch.. Yet something in there is keeping this from working.

This might look like a duplicate of some other questions out there, but I've tried everything from the ones I've found. I've even uninstalled MVC 2 from my machine. Suggestions/help would be most welcome!

Thank you...

Comment: I have always [manually](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) upgraded all my existing ASP.NET MVC 2 applications. I never trust any automated tools. I've never had any problems with it. The process is simple and quite straightforward. All I can say is: try it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Darin! I'll try that -- might not get to it until Monday, but I'll let you know how it goes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here..

It turns out that the MVC 2 app (which I didn't write, btw) used a custom ViewEngine, which derived from WebFormViewEngine. When I converted my partial view to razor, I added "~/Views/Shared/Modules/{0}.cshtml" to the locations array in that class, without realizing that it'd be using the WebFormViewEngine.

So, I ended up creating my own ViewEngine, which derives from RazorViewEngine... and added my /Modules path to that one instead. It works!

Starting over fresh and manually converting the app to MVC 3 helped (thanks again Darin D), because it forced me to go through all the steps myself, and caused me to find this issue.

Comment: Makes sense - glad you tracked it down! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing the two projects to see if there are any significant differences - specifically the Web.config (though maybe settings in the csproj too). Things like the base type used for views/pages are stored in the web.config, so it's possible they're set incorrectly, or even missing from your original project.

A default MVC project has things like this in the web.config in the views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

and

```
<pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Comment: Thanks Danny -- I have checked that stuff already, actually. It helped to get Intellisense working for Razor, but didn't solve the bigger issues. I'm going to try starting over with manually converting the MVC2 app to 3.

Comment: Thanks again -- I gave you an upvote because that *was* part of the issue, but.. well, see my answer for the real issue. :)